# identity based encryption-Private key

Tags: identity-based-encryption

PKG will be sending the Private key,so it may not be secure,some one may get the private key,how to overcome this problem in IBE. Please help am unable to justify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBE without key escrow](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/45295/61539)

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42879/how-are-private-keys-handed-to-users-in-identity-based-encryption